# Shape union in processing?

Tags: processing, shapes

I'm learning processing and trying to create an SVG file containing a complex shape (path) which should be a union of a hexagon and a rectangle. But, unfortunately, I can't find any set operations on PShape.

[image: a hexrect]

Comment: Found similar question on [discourse.processing.org](https://discourse.processing.org/t/boolean-operation-in-polygons/23439?u=kelin)

Comment: [PGS](https://github.com/micycle1/PGS) provides shape boolean operations for Processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found useful ErraticGenerator's [answer](https://discourse.processing.org/t/boolean-operation-in-polygons/23439/11?u=kelin) on Processing forum. The idea is to use **g.js** library mixed with **p5js** drawing methods.

Include the script in index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodebox/g.js/master/dist/g.min.js"></script>
```

Sketch example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400)
  noLoop()
}

function draw() {
  let rect = g.rect(50, 50, 100, 100)
  let ellipse = g.ellipse(100, 100, 100, 100)
  let union = g.compound(rect, ellipse, 'union')
  union.fill = null
  union.stroke = 'red'
  union.draw(drawingContext)
}
```

[image: Path union]

This also works in combo with **p5.js-svg**!